# Question about two positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have two symmetric matrices $A,B$ such that the following hold for all nontrivial $x$

$x^T A x > x^T B x > 0$

Is it true that

$x^T A^{-1} x < x^T B^{-1} x$

Seems straightforward, but I've had a really hard time proving/disproving this. Any thoughts?

Comment: If the matrices are $1\times 1$ its obvious. The general case reduces to this case by diagonalizing simultaneously both matrices.

Comment: Or you can just look at the eigenvalues ...

Comment: @Gil Bor:  What if $A$ and $B$ cannot be simultaneously diagonalized?

Comment: @RobertLewis: what I meant is diagonalize the quadratic forms, not the matrices (find a basis where both $x^tAx, x^tBx$ are linear combination of squares). This is always possible for a pair of quadratic forms, if at least one of them is positive definite (in this problem both are assumed to be positive definite).

Comment: @GilBor:  OK, I don't know much about quadratic forms but you sound convincing.  I'll have to learn more . . . thanks for the response!  Illuminating!

Comment: @RobertLewis: this is a reformulation of the (perhaps) more familiar result: a symmetric matrix can be **orthogonaly** diagonalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can assume that $A=I$ by the substitution $x = A^{-1/2} z$ where $A^{1/2}$ is the symmetric square root of $A$. 
Then your condition reads
$$
z^t C z < z^t z \\
C = A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2}
$$
This shows that $C < I$. Hence $C^{-1} > I$. The result follows.